# Problema con : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 al pasar datos de un jtable a otro

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, jtable, jtextfield

estoy intentando pasar multiples filas de un jtable a otro en Netbeans. Mi idea es la siguiente:
[image: tabla que quiero copiar]

Quiero que se me pasen los primeros X filas del primer jtable al segundo al hacer click en el boton mostrar, siendo X el numero mostrado en el jtextfield Porcentaje. No puedo poner que el usuario manualmente elija los datos dado que a veces son miles, por eso ese dato se obtiene al hacer el calculo en el textfield Porcentaje. Este es mi código del boton:

```
private void btn_MostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
  TableModel modelo1 = jTable1.getModel();
  int[] fila1 = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
    double filas = Double.parseDouble(tf_Porcentaje.getText());
    Object [] row = new Object[9];
    
    DefaultTableModel modelo2 = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
    
    for(int i = 0; i <= filas; i++){
        row[0] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 0);
        row[1] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 1);
        row[2] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 2);
        row[3] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 3);
        row[4] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 4);
        row[5] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 5);
        row[6] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 6);
        row[7] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 7);
        row[8] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 8);
        
        modelo2.addRow(row);
    }
}
```

Pero al clickearlo me sale este error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at clases.Inventario.btn_MostrarActionPerformed(Inventario.java:1257)
at clases.Inventario.access$400(Inventario.java:22)
at clases.Inventario$5.actionPerformed(Inventario.java:754)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 0):

El error que estás obteniendo se debe a que estás intentando acceder a una fila del `JTable` seleccionada que no existe, ya que en la línea `int[] fila1 = jTable1.getSelectedRows();` estás obteniendo las filas seleccionadas del `JTable`, y si no hay ninguna fila seleccionada, el arreglo `fila1` estará vacío, y si intentas acceder a alguna posición del arreglo que no existe, se producirá la excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Para solucionar esto, debes comprobar si hay alguna fila seleccionada en el `JTable` antes de continuar con el proceso de copiar las filas. Podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
private void btn_MostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    TableModel modelo1 = jTable1.getModel();
    int[] fila1 = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
    double filas = Double.parseDouble(tf_Porcentaje.getText());
    Object [] row = new Object[9];
    
    DefaultTableModel modelo2 = (DefaultTableModel)jTable2.getModel();
    
    if (fila1.length > 0) { // Verificar si hay alguna fila seleccionada
        for(int i = 0; i < filas && i < fila1.length; i++){ // Utilizar "i < fila1.length" para evitar la excepción
            row[0] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 0);
            row[1] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 1);
            row[2] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 2);
            row[3] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 3);
            row[4] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 4);
            row[5] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 5);
            row[6] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 6);
            row[7] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 7);
            row[8] = modelo1.getValueAt(fila1[i], 8);

            modelo2.addRow(row);
        }
    }
}
```

En este caso, se está utilizando la condición `if (fila1.length > 0)` para verificar si hay alguna fila seleccionada, y se está utilizando `i < fila1.length` en el ciclo `for` interno para evitar la excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Además, se está utilizando `i < filas && i < fila1.length` en la condición del ciclo `for` para asegurarse de que no se copien más filas de las que hay seleccionadas o de las que se especifican en el `JTextField`.

Comment: al hacer eso se me quita el error pero las filas no se agregan a menos que sean seleccionadas manualmente, mi idea es que obtenga las X primeras filas (siendo X el valor del textfield) y que esas filas sean mostradas en el nuevo jtable, sin que el usuario tenga que estar agregando manualmente 690 registros (citando el ejemplo que tengo en la imagen)

Comment: @G.Torres En ese caso no deberías utilizar `fila[i]` ya que no hay filas seleccionadas, si no que simplemente debes utilizar `i` del for que representa la fila que se esta recorriendo.

Comment: @JFrame seguí tu consejo y aún así no se añaden automáticamente, hay que hacerlo manual

Comment: @G.Torres Pensá nomás: si la cantidad de filas _seleccionadas_ es mayor a cero, usá el `for` con `fila[i]`, **sino**, ¡hacé un `for` pero con `i`!

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btn_MostrarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {     
    TableModel modelo1 = jTable1.getModel();

      // obtiene cant filas para calcular el porcentaje
    int cantidadFilas = JTable1.getModel().getRowCount();
    double filas = Double.parseDouble( tf_Porcentaje.getText() );
      // calculamos la cantidad de filas de la 2° tabla
    int cantidadNueva = (int) ( cantidadFilas * filas / 100 );
      // obtengo la matriz original
    Object matrizA = JTable1.getModel().getMatriz();
    Object matrizB = new Object[ 8 ][ cantidadNueva ];

    for( int col = 0; col <= 8; col++ ){
        for( int row = 0; row <= cantidadNueva; row++ ){
            matrizB[ i ][ k ] = matrizA[ i ][ k ];
        }
    }  
    jTable2 = new JTable( matrizB );
}
```

Creo (aunque estoy un poco dormido), que esto debería funcionar.